# Foundational textbook(s) for Complexity and Computability on Real Numbers

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, soft-question, computability, computing-over-reals

It would be extremely helpful if someone can suggest foundational textbooks on Recursive Analysis (Computability over Reals) which explains connections between Computability and the Topological properties of continuous sets. I could not find any, except "Recursive Analysis" by R.L. Goodstein but I dont have any feedback on that book. I would also like to ask for suggestions regarding a book on Complexity over Real Numbers which again deals with the connection between the complexity and the topology of a set. The only book I found on the net was "Complexity and Real Computation" by Lenore Blum et al but I am not sure if that is the book which I am looking for. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good books - 
 1. Computable Analysis - Pour-El and Richards (an older reference)
 2. Computable Analysis - Weihrauch

There's also the Blum-Shub-Smale Model, which is the model explored in "Complexity and Real Computation".

The complexity theory of computability of reals is explored in 
 1. Computational Complexity of real functions  - Ker-I Ko

A regular conference which explores this area is "Computability and Complexity in Analysis", held annually.

Answer (score 1):

The website of [Computability and Complexity in Analysis Network](http://cca-net.de/) has extensive [bibliography](http://cca-net.de/publications/bibliography.php). See their page for [books](http://cca-net.de/publications/books.html).

For computability, see

- Klaus Weihrauch, "[Computable Analysis](http://www.fernuni-hagen.de/weihrauch/index_data/book.html)", 2010.

It also has a chpater on complexity.

See also PhD theses of Jens Blanc and Andrej Bauer.

Another interesting paper is

- Viggo Stoltenberg-Hansen and John Tucker, "Computability on Topological
  Spaces via Domain Representations", 1997.